# Does a php include() 'know' its requester?

Tags: php

Is it possible to put some code at the top of a PHP included file to prevent it from being included in any directory below a certain level in my directory tree? Considering the following directory structure:

```
|--Myapp
   |--includes
      |include-this-in-my-app-only.php
   |--index-for-my-app.php
   |--contact-for-my-app.php
   |--tenant-1-directory
      |--index-for-tenant-1.php
      |--contact-for-tenant-1.php
   |--tenant-2-directory
      |--index-for-tenant-2.php
      |--contact-for-tenant-2.php
   |--tenant-3-directory
      |--index-for-tenant-3.php
      |--contact-for-tenant-3.php
```

Can I add something at the top of my include file that forbids it from being included if it is being requested from any directory below my own? Or is there another approach? I am using a VPS.

Comment: You could examine the list of "included" files (including the index file) with [get_included_files()](http://php.net/get_included_files), to determine which tenant the include call came from.

Comment: Can you tell us more about your use-case? There may be a better way to solve your overall problem. In general, what you're proposing sounds like it would result in difficult to maintain code.

Comment: It sounds like, if you think you want or need this, something else is already more fundamentally wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can define a global constant in your code and in the included file check if its set to false or undefined then die(); that will block direct access to the file like this:

```
define('DIRECT', false);
```

in the file you will block access to:

```
if(!DIRECT || !defined('DIRECT')){
die('DIRECT ACCESS NOT ALLOWED');
}
```

Comment: I think this is my answer. Just to confirm, basically what I am doing is "seeding" each file by defining something. Then requiring the include file to have it accurately defined in order to load. Is that right? I know nothing in life is 100% secure and full proof, but are there any easy ways this could be hacked?

Comment: This won't be hacked bcoz there is no direct access allowed to the file unless you define the DIRECT constant in your code then require the file, please if this was the answer you was looking for don't forget to mark it as correct for this question :)

Answer (score 1):

You can run the function `debug_backtrace()` at the start of a PHP file to get the previous PHP file.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

To answer to your title question: no, an include file can't know who has called it. However, you can add a variable just before your include, to explain it who is the caller:

caller.php :

```
$caller = "caller a";
include("include.php");
```

include.php :

```
// here you can manage $caller to know exactly who has called.
echo $caller;
```

For your specific case, you can always transmit the path in $caller and then compare it with the path of include files.